# Is there a way to use the OneDrive API to store files and edit them directly from a link, without SSO authorization?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am creating an app and I would like have a feature, where users can upload files and access them. If those files are either .docx and .xlsx, I would like to store them in Microsoft OneDrive and allow the user to directly go and edit them via a link directly to Microsoft online. All of these documents would be stored in one OneDrive account (so the user wouldn't have to link their own). That means that I don't want the user to go beyond editing their document.

Is this a possible scenario or do I need to force the user to link their own OneDrive account in order to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file with the graph api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content

And then create an anonymous share link with this endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink